# Adding column of ones to features set

Tags: pandas, numpy

How do I add column of ones to the features set `X`?

My feature set is of order `mx1` and I want to make it `mx2` by add an extra column of ones. `m` is the number of rows.

```
x=[[np.ones((m,1))],X]
```

This is what I have done.

Feature set

[image]

Comment: pls include a [*reproducible*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) attempt here, not in an image - http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0):

Note that your X is a pd.Series, when you want to add a column of ones you are creating a pandas Dataframe.  Here is one method to do that:

```
X = X.to_frame().assign(col1=1)
```